# JavaScript setVariable to be a function

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I have a toolbar that has 4 values that need to be assigned after the page loads. `phone, contactus, feedback, chat` The first three are data elements that are being assigned just fine but the forth `chat` needs to be different based of off the user's region.

So I have a function that is a switch statement

```
const handleChatClick = (e) => {
        console.log('handle chat click fired')
        switch(customerCountry) {
            case('US'):
            case('CA'):
            case('PR'): {
               triggerChat('NAM');
         }
```

And I am assigning everything with `setVariable`

```
    toolbarOnThePage.setAttribute('phone', `${phoneNumberVariable}`);
    toolbarOnThePage.setAttribute('contactus', `${contactUsVariable}`);
    toolbarOnThePage.setAttribute('feedback', `${feedbackVariable}`);
    toolbarOnThePage.setAttribute('chat', `${handleChatClick()}`);
```

However this will assign `chat` to be a string version of my function. I have tried every combination I can think of: 
`${() => handleChatClick()}` `handleChatClick()` `${handleChatClick}` `handleChatClick` How can I set the attribute to be a function?

Comment: An HTML attribute can't be a function, it can only ever be a string.

Comment: also, if you are using custom HTML attributes, they should really have a name starting `data-` - so `data-phone`, `data-chat` etc.

Comment: Since attributes have to be strings, just add a click event listener that will then call the **handleChatClick**.

Comment: That would explain why I didn't find anything on google. I will go with Imvain2's method. Thank you all